# JS code supposed to save data into local storage; but nothing's happening

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I was trying to make an extension that stores current tab/window's URL(s) in the local storage. It doesn't have errors but everytime I try it out, the local storage shows no difference and the intended action isn't happening at all.

Here's the JS code I'm using:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Links") === null) {
    let urls = []
    localStorage.setItem("Links", JSON.stringify(urls)) 
}

document.getElementById("tablink").addEventListener("click", save_tab)
document.getElementById("windowlinks").addEventListener("click", save_window)

function save_tab()  {
    let urls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Links"))
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, tabs => {
        urls.push(tabs[0].url)
        localStorage.setItem("Links", JSON.stringify(urls))
    })
}

function save_window()  {
    let urls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Links"))
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        for (const tab of tabs) {
            urls.push(tab.url)
        }
        localStorage.setItem("Links", JSON.stringify(urls))
    })
}
```

Here's my github repo with the html file n all: https://github.com/Anushka-N12/CExtension
Please let ke know why nothing's happening in the local storage and how to correct it!

Comment: My test results contradict your claims. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDtgC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDtgC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not consistently allow access to `localStorage` depending on your cookie settings. [This issue](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/223) has more info and links to Chromium bug reports. The only known workaround is to rely on [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) instead.

Comment: I changed those lines to chrome.storage.local.set(....) but still same prob. I also added storage to permissions which I was missing earlier but that didn't seem to make a difference